# modifying tables in my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database with a table called members, which stores data for my admin,client,technicians all in one.But now I want to break this table into three separate tables as admin table,client table and techs table.As I have now written queries based on the members table I want to keep the common fields which were used in queries in the members table as they are now.Therefore I reduced the members table only to have fields ID,Name,UserName,Password,Level,Category.Throughout the site it is recognized if the user is a admin,client,or technician by setting levels(which corresponds to Level field).
When inserting data I tried using this code.First insert the common fields to members and then depending on the level write separate queries specifying to which table should data be inserted.

```
if($_POST['Submit']){
        if(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE UN='$r[UN]' AND ID!='$r[ID]' "))) {
             ?><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert('Username already exsits.Please enter another.');
             </script>
             <?php
             }
        else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (Name,UN,Password,Level,Category) VALUES ('$r[Name]','$r[UN]','$r[PW]','$r[Level]','$r[Category]')");
            $row=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Name='$r[Name]'") or die('query unsuccesful');

             if ($row['Level']==1){
                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO client(Name,Mobile,Phone,Fax,Email,Address) VALUES ('$r[Name]','$r[Mobile]','$r[Phone]','$r[Fax]','$r[Email]','$r[Address]')");
                 }
            elseif($row['Level']==2){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO techs (Name,,Category,Company,Price,Comments,Rate,Qualifications,Mobile,Phone,Fax,Email,Address) VALUES ('$r[Name]','$r[Category]','$r[Company]','$r[Price]','$r[Comments]','$r[Rate]','$r[Qualifications]','$r[Mobile]','$r[Phone]','$r[Fax]','$r[Email]','$r[Address]')");
                }
            else{           
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin (Name,Mobile,Phone,Fax,Email,Address) VALUES ('$r[Name]','$r[Mobile]','$r[Phone]','$r[Fax]','$r[Email]','$r[Address]')");
            }
            if(!$user){
                 $user=$r;
                 $_SESSION['user']=$r;
                  }
```

But data gets inserted only to members table and nothing goes for client,techs or admin.Any idea how I can mend this please

Comment: Why are you using a deprecated library?

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching data on the 2nd select.

```
$row=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Name='$r[Name]'") or die('query unsuccesful');
if(mysql_fetch_array($row)) {... }
```

Comment: Thanks now its working.What is the best field to keep relation in between these members,client,admin and techs tables.When a particular person is considered I have to take some of his information from members and the other from either client or techs table.Should I inculde UserName field in all of these tables